# Android Retrofit post request multipart encoding error

Tags: java, android, post, retrofit, multipart

I am facing this problem try to make post request with retrofit.

```
@Body parameters cannot be used with form or multipart encoding.
```

My body classes looks like below,

```
public class AddUser implements Serializable {
    public String memberNo;
    public List<AddUserLimit> limits;
}

public class AddUserLimit implements Serializable {
    public String type;
    public Value value;
}

public class Value implements Serializable {
    public String unit;
    public String unit_value;
}
```

And my interface method looks like below,

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api")
Call<ResponseBody> addMember(@QueryMap HashMap<String, Object> paramaters, @Body AddUser addUser);
```

I am waiting your helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the `@Body` annotation with an `@FormUrlEncoded` annotation. You must use an `@Part` annotation, this annotation will compose the request body for you.

Comment: I deleted the @FormUrlEncoded annotation and fixed. Thanks for your help.